# dates, nulls and indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a table, where i track events and their occurred date.
In some cases, event occurred date is null (even is not occurred yet, but already registered)

quick stats: all events 390k rows, 252k of which with null date

so i am having issues when pulling data based on user's request:
1. user may want pull events that are not occurred yet; (user enters *)
2. user may pull events that occurred beyond specific date; 
3. user may pull events that occurred beyond specific date + the ones that are not occurred yet;

i am building dynamic sql query, something like

```
select
  even_id,
  event_registered_date,
  event_name,
  event_occurred_date
from
  events_table
where
  NVL(event_occurred_date, to_date('2033-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) >= coalesce(to_date(replace(:p1, '*', NULL),'yyyy-mm-dd'),event_occurred_date,to_date('2033-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
  ...--other filter conditions are here
```

The most cost consuming part of this sql is date filter. I tried to create function based index `trunc(event_occurred_date)` and even including null values `trunc(NVL(event_occurred_date,to_date('2033-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')))` it still uses full table scan.

I am sure there's more delicate way of solving this, but i just do not see it.
Thanks in advance

**Added:**
I just talked to the table owner, and they told me that at least half of events will be having **nulls** for **event_occurred_date** at any given time. Maybe this will help to analyze
Execution plan is:
[image: execution plan]

Comment: Why aren't you setting your null date values with a default value (like 2033-01-01 you are populating dynamically with NVL)? It seems like a good solution to most of your problems.

Comment: Another solution can be splitting the query into two parts - one where date is null, which will naturally be slower (since there is no apparent filter and it is the bulk of the data - so indexing is not an option) and another where date is not null which will use an index to query date specific events.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot affect the way table gets populated, so i have to work as it is.
regarding the splitting into two rows, i can only use one sql query, and the part i have provided upper is one of the JOINs i use in bigger select. so this won't help either. thanks for your advice

Comment: With that ratio of null values, your first and third scenarios won't benefit from an index anyway - a full table scan will be quicker as you have to retrieve so many table blocks anyway. (Unless the other conditions can use indexes, which makes this moot anyway). The second scenario might benefit from a simple index on that column, but if so having a separate query for that might be simpler - is that feasible? And are the other conditions more selective and on indexed columns anyway?

Comment: regarding the splitting into two rows, i can only use one sql query, and the part i have provided upper is one of the JOINs i use in bigger select (an they have PK indexes and their cost is minimal (less than 3).

Answer (score 1):

First of all after building the index - have you analyzed the index?

Assuming you have - you do not mention which query type you are running.
If the query parameter is searching for NULL - I would not be surprised at the optimizer choosing to use a full table scan over an Index Range scan.
Afterall, the majority of your recordset has a NULL date value.

You can also use a hint to force the use of the Index 
ie. /*+ index(events_table_idx) */

But you need to look closely at the performance stats to determine which way is the most efficient way to retrieve your data.

Comment: there is no `where event_occurred_date is NULL` part in the result sql select. it should fit general pattern:
when user enters `*` - then i should skip checking `event_occurred_date` (means, regardless even has occurred date or not, including nulls), when user enters a date, then it should check against entered date.
and yes i tried specifying the index hint and it still uses full table scan, and i think that is truely faster than having a range scan on an index.